# C++ how to catch an exception?

Tags: c++, exception

I am trying to catch pointer exception. My code looks like this. I am getting "Unhandled exception". What is it that I am doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

int list_length(struct Node* head){
    try{
        int i = 0;
        while (head->next){
            head = head->next;
            i++;
        }
        return i + 1;
    }
    catch (exception& e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
};

int main(void){

    struct Node *perr = nullptr;
    list_length(perr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no C++ exception here. You just dereference null pointer, that is undefined behaviour, not exception. You should just check, that `head` is not nullptr before dereference it. Probably, you are using windows and windows exception is thrown. You can read here: [How to catch the null pointer exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823721/how-to-catch-the-null-pointer-exception)

Comment: Yes, I am using windows. Now I see, thanks.